# Arduino Uno blink onboard LED by an assembly code gives error Found no label/variable/constant named PD0

Tags: linux, assembly, arduino, avr, arduino-uno

I have found an assembly code as follows

blink.asm

```
; blink.asm

; Pin Constant Values
; PD0 - 0
; PD1 - 1
; PD2 - 2
; PD3 - 3
; PD4 - 4
; PD5 - 5
; PD6 - 6
; PD7 - 7

; PB0 - 8
; PB1 - 9
; PB2 - 10
; PB3 - 11
; PB4 - 12
; PB5 - 13 - System LED

.DEF PTD = r16
.DEF PTB = r17

.MACRO Delay1
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
    rcall delay
.ENDMACRO

start:
    rcall   init ; Initialize pins
loop:
    Delay1
    rcall   setpinhigh
    Delay1
    rcall   setpinlow
    rjmp    loop

init:
    ; Set pins 0-7 to low
    ldi     r16,(0<<PD7)|(0<<PD6)|(0<<PD5)|(0<<PD4)|(0<<PD3)|(0<<PD2)|(0<<PD1)|(0<<PD0)
    out     PORTD,r16

    ; Set pins 8-13 to low
    ldi     r17,(0<<PB5)|(0<<PB4)|(0<<PB3)|(0<<PB2)|(0<<PB1)|(0<<PB0)
    out     PORTB,r17

    ; Set pins 0-7 to output mode
    ldi     r18,(1<<DDD7)|(1<<DDD6)|(1<<DDD5)|(1<<DDD4)|(1<<DDD3)|(1<<DDD2)|(1<<DDD1)|(1<<DDD0)
    out     DDRD,r18

    ; Set pins 8-13 to output mode
    ldi     r19,(1<<DDB5)|(1<<DDB4)|(1<<DDB3)|(1<<DDB2)|(1<<DDB1)|(1<<DDB0)
    out     DDRB,r19

    nop ; nop for settling down after pins set

    ret ; return from subroutine

setpinhigh:
    ldi     PTD,1<<PD0
    out     PORTD, PTD
    ret
setpinlow:
    ldi     PTD,0<<PD0
    out     PORTD, PTD
    ret
delay:
    ldi ZH,HIGH(65535)
    ldi ZL,LOW(65535)
count:
    sbiw ZL,1
    brne count
    ret
```

To blink the onboard LED of my Arduino uno (ATmega328P processor).

I tried to compile the code to hex by this command

```
avra blink.asm
```

But I receive

```
AVRA: advanced AVR macro assembler Version 1.3.0 Build 1 (8 May 2010)
Copyright (C) 1998-2010. Check out README file for more info

   AVRA is an open source assembler for Atmel AVR microcontroller family
   It can be used as a replacement of 'AVRASM32.EXE' the original assembler
   shipped with AVR Studio. We do not guarantee full compatibility for avra.

   AVRA comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
   You may redistribute copies of avra under the terms
   of the GNU General Public License.
   For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING.

Pass 1...
Warning : No .DEVICE definition found. Cannot make useful address range check !
Pass 2...
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD7
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD6
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD5
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD4
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD3
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD2
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD1
blink.asm(62) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PD0
blink.asm(63) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PORTD
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB5
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB4
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB3
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB2
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB1
blink.asm(66) : Error   : Found no label/variable/constant named PB0
blink.asm(66) : Maximum error count reached. Exiting...
done

Used memory blocks:
   Code      :  Start = 0x0000, End = 0x0040, Length = 0x0041

Assembly aborted with 15 errors and 1 warnings.
```

How to fix these errors?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'd consider the errors to be pretty clear. You define `PTD` and `PTB`, but not those pin-specific values.

Comment: @ThomasJager, Thanks. Can you please advise on how to fix them? No idea how to define the pins.

Comment: Ideally, you'd have some pre-made assembly include file, that has everything you need. Barring that, you need to add more lines like `.DEF PD7= some_number_here`, based on the values in the datasheet (or just wherever you cna find them).

Comment: You can see from usage that these are constants and represent the bit position in a byte of the port.  So, you might try PD0=0; PD1=1; PD2=2...  The value `(1<<PDn)` will put a 1 in `PDn`s bit position.  (There's really no need to have used `(0<<XX)` since that's just 0.)

Comment: @ThomasJager, `.def` needs a register and `equ` gives me error `Unknown mnemonic/macro`.

Comment: It looks like there are problems with `ZH` and `ZL` too. I feel a library inclusion is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error tell you that the assembler does not know what you mean by `PD0`, `PD1`...etc

#### Solution

instead of define registers and pin  from scratch these definitions already there... you can download and use [m328Pdef.inc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkSector/AVR/master/asm/include/m328Pdef.inc)

Add it in the same folder with your code then include it in the top of your code as following

```
.include "./m328Pdef.inc"
```

**Note that**:
[m328Pdef.inc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarkSector/AVR/master/asm/include/m328Pdef.inc) is just some Register and Bit Definitions for the ATmega328P